# Why is python so outdated on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to programming as well as Linux. Will using Python 2.7.6 as opposed to the latest version affect 
my learning?

Comment: questions about Ubuntu could be asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*nix distributions use Python for many of their core system utilities, and as a result, they are a bit conservative on moving to new versions, especially major non-backward-compatible versions like Python 3.  You should have a Python 3 interpreter available on Ubuntu though, you just have to run `python3` from the terminal instead of just `python`.  That said, for introductory programming, differences between 2 and 3 are negligible (to say nothing of differences between minor versions), so you should be fine with whatever interpreter you have access to.

Comment: When I type python 3 into a blank terminal. I'm returned with a can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @josh - try `python3` (without the space)

Comment: Yeah Padraic I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: @Josh: Make sure to accept the answer if it addressed your question perfectly.

Comment: The biggest difference (to the brand new beginner) is that in python2, you do `print "something"` while in python3 you do `print("something")`. Just be aware of what your tutorial is telling you to do :)

Comment: @AdamSmith `print('something')` will work largelythe same in Python 2 for most basic usecases.  It just gets interpreted as the result of the code block within the parens being provided as the input to the `print` statement instead of as arguments to a function call.

Comment: @SilasRay right but since your answer recommends using a py3 interpreter and (in my experience) most tutorials are still for python2... :)

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 has improvements that are not compatible with Python 2, so Python 2 is still needed for a lot of software that hasn't been upgraded.

You can install Python 3 alongside Python 2.

For someone who's just learning, it makes sense to use Python 3 *unless* you're in a class or company that's using Python 2. The improvements are worthwhile and easier to work with. It's not difficult to apply knowledge of one to the other, but better to focus on one of them while learning.

Answer (score 1):

Both python (Python 2) and python3 (Python 3) are installed on Ubuntu 14.04 by default. [For both Ubuntu and Debian, we have ongoing project goals to make Python 3 the default, preferred Python version in the distros](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3).

There are many scripts that were written for Python 2 that expect that `python` refers to Python 2 interpreter. Run `python3` to get Python 3 interpreter.